# Magnetic Float Switch inside Filling Nozzle

Tags: fluid-mechanics

I want to design a Liquid Flow Nozzle that has a Magnetic Float Switch inside, The Idea behind is that there is a system that has a Manifold with 10 to 12 Nozzles connected with it.

Now I want to fill different sizes of bottles let’s say 350ml or 1000ml but liquid should be filled equally in all bottles simultaneously.

No matter what pressure comes out from the Manifold Nozzles each nozzle has a Magnetic Float switch inside and when the liquid level is up then it closes the solenoid that will be attached to each nozzle

I don’t know if that idea is valid or not, but I would appreciate it if someone participated with their opinions

[image]

Comment: Look at how fuel pumps pump petrol etc Also how are bottles of different sizes expected top be filled simultaneously if some have to stop earlier than others?

Comment: "*Now I want to fill different sizes of bottles let’s say 350ml or 1000ml but liquid should be filled equally in all bottles simultaneously.*" Maybe reword this as, "I want to fill sets of identical bottles (say, 350 ml or 1000 ml) simultaneously with independent shutoff when full."

Comment: my input is that fill machines have been manufactured for a good century and I would not try to redesign them, I would buy one.

Comment: One would expect asking for opinions is asking to have the question closed.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: Look into buying liquid level sensors at least if not the fill system itself.  They vary from the bulb in the toilet tanks to the capacitive sensors used in some devices...

Comment: My concern is how quickly would such a system be to stop the flow of liquid to avoid the possibility of overflowing the liquid into each bottle. I'm envisaging the magnetic float may need to be elongated, with most of it inside the neck of the bottle & the bottle maybe needing to have a long neck. The flow rate of the liquid filling each bottle would also be critical to avoiding overfilling with such a system.